# How to retrieve data from mongodb based on iso date time format using python

Tags: python, mongodb, date, datetime, pymongo

This is my mongodb document,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c198f53869650eb0e2bc7a"), "Date" : ISODate("2016-02-15T14:50:14Z"), "nocontract" : 299039, "turnover" : 14882.65, "instrument" : "NSEFUT"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c19ffe3869650eb0e2bc7b"), "Date" : ISODate("2016-02-15T15:20:45Z"), "nocontract" : 334464, "turnover" : 16650.6, "instrument" : "NSEFUT"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c1a7073869650eb0e2bc7c"), "Date" : ISODate("2016-02-15T15:30:15Z"), "nocontract" : 351399, "turnover" : 17487.73, "instrument" : "NSEFUT"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c1ae103869650eb0e2bc7d"), "Date" : ISODate("2016-02-15T15:30:15Z"), "nocontract" : 351401, "turnover" : 17487.84, "instrument" : "NSEFUT"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c1b5183869650eb0e2bc7e"), "Date" : ISODate("2016-02-15T15:30:15Z"), "nocontract" : 351401, "turnover" : 17487.84, "instrument" : "NSEFUT"}
```

I need to query respect to the iso date.when i provide 10:00 ,whatever the records is there in my database at 10:00 that should i need to retrieve through python.
    Here i have written the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pymongo import MongoClient

conn = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db = conn.index
x = datetime.today()
off = 10
n = off + 1
y = x.replace(day=x.day, hour=off, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

date1 = datetime(2016, 1, 15, off, 0, 0)

for r in db.turnover.find({ 'Date': {'$gte': date1, '$lt': y}}):
    print r
```

But when i try to run this ,its not giving the proper output as i want..Can anyone help me out in solving this issue because i am new to python and mongodb.

Comment: please review the documents you gave. Do they really have that strange amount of whitespace in it? Also it does not become clear what your objective is. Maybe you can work this out, e.g. by explaining the expected result in terms of the sample data you gave...

Comment: Try changing the following parts: *db = conn['yourDbName']*,  *col = db['collectionName']*  and *col.find(...)*

Comment: unrelated: `datetime.today()` returns the current time in the local timezone, use `datetime.utcnow()` to get UTC time (used by MongoDB).

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer sruthy for your question,

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
#make the mongodb connection to your localhost
conn=MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db=conn['index']#connection to your database
r=[]
for doc in db['turnover'].find():
      y=doc['time'].year
      m=doc['time'].month
      d=doc['time'].day
      c=db['turnover'].find({"time":datetime(y,m,d,10,0,0)}).count()
      if c>0:
          a=db['turnover'].find({"time":datetime(y,m,d,10,0,0)})
          for ele in a:
              r2.append(ele)
print r
```